# how can hide a preference from the screen

Tags: android

I have an class `Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. I'm loading preferences from the xml file. But in some cases I need completely hide one of the preferences  screen based on my app state.  I want to remove that preference from the screen completely. Is it possible ? I need only `settings_account` and all other hide

```
<Preference
            android:title="Account Settings"
             android:key="customPref" />

<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/account_1"
                android:key="account">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="username"
            android:title="@string/settings_username"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="password"
            android:title="@string/settings_password"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
            </PreferenceScreen>


<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/account_2"
            android:key="account1">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="username1"
            android:title="@string/settings_username"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="password1"
            android:title="@string/settings_password"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
            </PreferenceScreen>
```

```
    android:title="@string/settings_pbxes_options">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="par"
            android:title="@string/settings_par"
            android:summary="@string/settings_par2" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="improve"
            android:title="@string/settings_improve"/>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="posurl"
            android:title="@string/settings_posurl"
            android:hint="https://www1.pbxes.com/name"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pos"
            android:title="@string/settings_pos"
            android:summary="@string/settings_pos2" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="callback"
            android:title="@string/settings_callback"
            android:summary="@string/settings_callback2" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="callthru"
            android:title="@string/settings_callthru"
            android:summary="@string/settings_callback2" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="callthru2"
            android:title="@string/settings_callthru2"
            android:hint="Accessno.,PIN#"
            android:singleLine="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a second preference xml and load it instead.

Comment: see if you are accessing elements that are removed in second case. That may cause errors

Answer (score 0):

If your Preference is within a PreferenceCategory, do as below 
XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="category_foo"
    android:title="foo">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkPref" />
```

Java:

```
CheckBoxPreference mCheckBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkPref");
PreferenceCategory mCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_foo");
mCategory.removePreference(mCheckBoxPref);
```

OR u can do:

```
myPreferenceScreen.removePreference(myPreference);
```

Comment: when i use remove preference the app crashes whem the screen is opened